# Can't log in to the forum from my other computer

Tags: firefox

I can't log in to the forum from a computer with wind 7 sp1 spanish, x86, windows interface language english, and with the last version of FireFox.

This is the screen I get when I try to log in:

[image]

These buttons are useless.

But from this computer, Wind7 sp1 spanish, x64, windows interface language english, and also with the last version of FireFox, I get this other screen when trying to log in:

[image]

This screen allows me to enter the forum.

What could I do to be able to enter with the previous computer? I always have used it with no problem, but I don't really know what changed.

Comment: Are you not able to log in to meta either? You have an account there, but you asked your question on main... and this is decidedly *not* about the API despite the tags.

Comment: I entered the forum from the computer that allows me to do so, the second option. What I can´t do is to log in from the first described computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know how to enter the forum from the first computer. Just click the entering option and then submit.

I'm not used tu use it since I never saw it before.

But I wonder why are there two different log in screens from two different computers!!

[image]